# Ember.js - One test always fails in random module

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

all my tests pass, but one error occurs every run on a random module. Even if its an empty controller, or route.

The message says:

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Attempting to lookup an injected property      on an object without a container, ensure that the object was instantiated via a     container.

[image]

Does someone know how to debug it?

Ember: 2.2.0

Ember-Data 2.2.0

Ember-Cli: 2.2.0-beta-3

Comment: check to see if there's a module or controller or some other code that isn't tearing down correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the mixins required a service that could not be injected. After mocking it, it works again.